# Running tcpdump in parallel in C progam

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, popen, tcpdump

I am writing a C program for some network measurements. What I would like to achieve is the following. In the main program I am sending some packets and I need to capture the responses and write them to a log file (the log is rather sophisticated so not only the dumps are there). In order to achieve that I am creating a thread which should do the job. Inside that thread I have to start tcpdump which is done by calling a modified `popen()` function which also returns a `pid` of the process. See the code below:

```
// Thread part
void *tcpdump_capture(void *pack_type) {

    char *capture;
    capture = (char *) pack_type;
    printf("capturing: %s\n", capture);
    pid_t pid;

    FILE *fp;
    char tcpdump_resp[4096];

    fp = popen1("tcpdump -nnvvS -c1 udp and src xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to popen1()!\n" );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets(tcpdump_resp, sizeof(tcpdump_resp), fp) != NULL) {
        // Only displaying now, later it would be written to the log file
        printf("capture: %s\n", tcpdump_resp);
    }

    // Pid can be obtained like that 
    //pid = get_pid();

    pclose1(fp);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

...

// Main
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   ...

   // Starting capture
   ret = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, tcpdump_capture, (void *)"udp"); 
   if (ret) {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", ret);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }   

    usleep(10000);

    // Sending a packet
    send_some_packet(...);

    // Waiting for a thread to terminate
    ret = pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    if (ret) {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", ret);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ...
}
```

This setting works ok. I can see the dump of the received packet. Now to the problems. As can be seen from the code, currently I am using `-c1` parameter in tcpdump. However, since I do not know how many packets I would get in advance (maybe none at all) this setting is not reliable. Moreover, if the `-c1` parameter is removed the only data that I can capture in this case is `tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes`. Then I have to manually ^CTRL+C both the tcpdump and the shell that invoked it.

What I would like to have is the following. I am starting tcpdump then I am capturing the received packet (if any) or waiting for a specified timer to expire. After that I need to kill both the tcpdump process and the shell that invoked it (that is why I am obtaining pid(-s)). Finally, the thread would terminate.

I know that it sounds a bit complex, but I could not find a feasible solution so far. Maybe there are better or more optimal ways to do that.

P.S. The capture have to happen inside the C program since I maintain numerous parameters: packet types, IP addresses, ports, etc. So launching tcpdump in other terminal is not a solution since it is not salable at all.

Comment: Why do you launch tcpdump at all -- that is, why don't you provide your own implementation dedicated to your needs within your program, by making use of libpcap?

Comment: @mah Thanks. Yep, I was thinking about that as well, but at the beginning I decided to go for something "off-the shelf" and easier to use (at least what I thought initially). But now I am getting more and more convinced that implementing everything with libpcap would be much more feasible, because I spent numerous amount of hours trying to make the above mentioned setting work. I wonder if it possible at all and would it be reliable? Definitely with the method that I had posted there would be a performance penalty due to shell invocation.

Comment: The performance penalty due to the shell would be negligible but you're also consuming two additional processes. If that mattered and you wanted to still use tcpdump as an external process, since you're modifying `popen()` you could modify it further to start the process directly. As to possible/reliable use of libpcap -- as long as you get the code right, it will be! After all, that's how tcpdump does it's thing ;)

Comment: Actually, for the reliability I meant the setting that I am currently using (I know that libpcap is ok ;)). Since, I have two additional processes and I need to explicitly kill them afterwards I suppose there is a chance to run into the race conditions or something. Could you please provide a bit more information on how to start a process directly (in terms of popen)? A small code snippet or a link would be very helpful. Thanks for clarifying comments.

Comment: I cannot provide a code snippet  but I assume you're comfortable with the source to popen() since you've made a version of it. popen() calls execl() with arguments something like `("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", program, NULL)`. The first argument here is the path to where the executable is on disk, and the remaining arguments are the `argv[]` items for the program being started. Get your tcpdump arguments there any way you like (based on how generic/complicated you want things), but something simple like `("/usr/sbin/tcpdump", "tcpdump", "-nnvvS", "-c1", ..., NULL)` and you'll remove the shell.

Comment: Ok, now it is clear. Thank you very much for your help!